# If $f(x)$ is a differentiable function such that $f(x) \leqslant f(3)$ for $1\leqslant x\leqslant 3$, then which is true?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> If $f(x)$ is a differentiable function such that $f(x) \leqslant f(3)$
> for $1\leqslant x\leqslant 3$, then
>
> a. $\quad f'(3) =0 $
>
> b. $\quad f'(3) =f(3)  $
>
> c. $\quad f'(3) =3$
>
> d. $\quad f'(3)$ does not exist

I've tried to solve this problem by considering $f(x) =x$.
Then $f'(3) =1$,
which is not among the options.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, $f(x)=x$ is differentiable and it attains the global maximum at $3$.

Something seems to be missing from the question.

One possible modification is that $f$ attains a global maximum at $x=3$ over a larger domain, for example $[1, 4]$. Notice that under this modification, $f(x)=x$ is no longer a valid example.